# Jquery polyfill plugin to apply bootstrap.css to bootstrap modal?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome-extension, bootstrap-modal

Guys I am injecting a `bootstrap modal` in `mail.google.com`. For this I need `bootstrap.css` but it contains `style` properties for `html,body,a,img` which conflicts with gmail UI and changes it. So I decided to use `<style scoped>` but chrome doesn't support it. I searched and found a `Jquery` polyfill plugin  that simulates the functionality you'd expect from `<style scoped>` :

https://github.com/thingsinjars/jQuery-Scoped-CSS-plugin

I tested it on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yqvm7/15/) but it is not working in my extension. Here's my code:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Extension",
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "Gmail Modal",
  "icons": { "16": "icons/icon16.png",
             "48": "icons/icon48.png",
            "128": "icons/icon128.png" },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://mail.google.com/*"],
      "css":["css/modal.css"],

      "js": [ "lib/jquery/jquery.min.js",
              "lib/jquery-scoped/jquery.scoped.js",
              "lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
               "content/content.js"
             ],
    "run_at":"document_end"
    }
  ],
   "web_accessible_resources": [
    "modal.html",
    "lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
    "lib/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot",
    "lib/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg",
    "lib/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf",
    "lib/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff",
    "lib/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2"

  ],


    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

**content.js**

```
    $.scoped();        
    $.get(chrome.extension.getURL('modal.html'), function(data) {
      $(data).appendTo('body');
     });
```

**modal.html**

```
<div>
<style scoped>
  @import url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@<extension_id_here>/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
</style>
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

It should work but still elements of Gmail elements are loading `styles` from `bootstrap.css`.

**EDIT:**

I followed wOxxOm advice. Instead of using `@import` i added the `bootstrap` contents inside `<style scoped>`. Also I called `$.scoped()` after `html` was injected

**content.js**

```
 $.get(chrome.extension.getURL('lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'), function(css) {
        $.get(chrome.extension.getURL('modal.html'), function(modal) {

          $("<div>" + "<style scoped>" + css + "</style>" + modal + "</div>").appendTo('body');
          $.scoped();

        });
    });
```

Now `gmail UI` doesn't change but my injected `html`'s all elements are loading every possible style properties from `bootstrap.css`(there are lots of style properties and every element has same properties)

Comment: I think `__MSG_@@` isn't needed if you specify the extension id explicitly. Also that library says `Sometimes there are delays parsing externally loaded stylesheets (via @import) and they might get skipped. Not often but it happens.` so try embedding the contents of `bootstrap.css` inside `<style scoped>` element.

Comment: @wOxxOm   I followed your advice but having another issues. I edited the answer.

Comment: So does it look properly? As for all elements having the CSS rules, maybe it's what that polyfill lib does (how would it work otherwise)?

Comment: @wOxxOm I checked the jsfiddle and same thing is happening there. I guess this lib works this way. But in my case, it overwrites my applied css and modal doesn't show